# Get all CFBundleTypeExtensions of an Info.plist

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, info.plist

I would like to get all the extensions of files my app can open. And I'd like to get them from my Info.plist. Right now I have this, but is there a better alternative?

```
NSMutableArray *types = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *documentTypes = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey: @"CFBundleDocumentTypes"];
for (NSDictionary *dict in documentTypes) {
    for (NSString *extension in [dict objectForKey: @"CFBundleTypeExtensions"])
        [types addObject: extension];
}
return [types autorelease];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's probably the most efficient way, though is there any reason why you have to check your Info.plist for this? Don't you already know which file types you can open?

Comment: Yes. But it's a big list... Maybe I should hardcode them instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the info.plist of your project just enter an asterisks ('*') as an item of CFBundleTypeExtension as shown in the picture below.

[image]